# How can I inspect how styles are adopted through vscode or emulator on selected widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm using FlutterSDK and vsCode as editor.
And I wonder how or what kind of style adopted to selected items or widget on certain emulator, as it's difficult to find that on my codes.

Is there some functions or plug-in on emulators or vsCode editor?

It's helpful for me to treat it as if I can check it on Chrome developer tools CSS inspector.
THanks

Comment: Do you want to find a code just by clicking on the widget?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but I don't mind if it is clicked on the emulator or something plugged in  vsCode editor.

Comment: I have given the answer please check and follow the step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the widget tree, performance, network calls and memory usage, we have dart dev tool in flutter.

To check the code just by clicking the widget on screen of your mobile or emulator.

[image]

After clicking "Selected widget mode" Click on your emultaor screen. Vs code will take you to the clicked widget in the widget tree.

Comment: Wow, Thanks for super super helpful comment!! It's gonna help me a lot!

Comment: You can upvote and select this answer as solution, if it's solve your query. This motivate us to help more developers.

Comment: I'm new about sof and didn't know how to close the question. And I Actually checked the mark above,  did it work as you told ?

Answer (score 1):

### Flutter Inspector

The tool you're asking for is the [Flutter Inspector](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/inspector).

You can get it on your VS Code by installing the [Flutter VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter).

The Flutter Inspector shows up automatically with the Flutter DevTools when you run your app in debug mode.

A screenshot of Flutter Inspector is shown below:

[image: A screenshot of Flutter Inspector]

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I'm gonna use the tools!